# When running a TF graph which functions should use CPU and which functions should GPUs when we have Multi GPUs?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

We can assign different devices to do different operations in a Tensorflow Graph with **tf.device('cpu or gpu')** , It's not clear how to divide them .
Other thing is if we use the default thing does TF always uses GPU if there's a GPU?

**UPDATE**

When have two GPUs how to divide operations . Can **allow_soft_device_placement**  automatically do that ?

Comment: Yes, by default it's supposed to do "the most efficient thing possible", which right now means using GPU for everything it can

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov what if these functions don't have a gpu kernel?

Comment: And what if I have 2 GPUs .So if we use default connection will it run in the most efficient way by automatically sharing the GPU memory /

Comment: @Jie.Zhou then it runs on CPU. Furthermore, if there are colocation constraints on ops (ie, op=tf.assign(var,...) will add colocation constraint between `op` and `var` for efficiency), it will force all ops with colocation constraints to run on same device, so if any op doesn't have GPU impl, the whole group will run on CPU. The logic is in [common_runtime/placer.cc](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/37f7ad75bbd2ca140d1092342eb3590d54193bc8/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc#L397)

Comment: @ShamaneSiriwardhana multi-GPU default device placement is not yet solved with placer.cc, it puts everything on GPU:0 and ignores the rest

Comment: So how can I make use of second GPU I have. Can You explain the logical way of divining each operation in two GPUs ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finding a device in TF works as follows:

1. Check if there are [devices at all](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc#L654)
2. sanity-check if nodes manually assigned to devices [can really run](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc#L504-L536) on these devices
3. prefer [consumer nodes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc#L750-L759) as hints for device placement
4. check [all constraints](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc#L761-L768) to just use valid devices
5. use default device [if no other devices is chosen](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc#L797-L800)

There is an understandable test:
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/3bc73f5e2ac437b1d9d559751af789c8c965a7f9/tensorflow/core/grappler/costs/virtual_placer_test.cc#L26-L54
which boils down to

```
TEST(VirtualPlacerTest, LocalDevices) {
  // Create a virtual cluster with a local CPU and a local GPU
  std::unordered_map<string, DeviceProperties> devices;
  devices[".../cpu:0"] = cpu_device;
  devices[".../device:GPU:0"] = gpu_device;

  NodeDef node;
  node.set_op("Conv2D");
  // node.device() is empty, but GPU is default device if there is.
  EXPECT_EQ("GPU", placer.get_device(node).type());

  node.set_device("CPU");
  EXPECT_EQ("CPU", placer.get_device(node).type());

  node.set_device("GPU:0");
  EXPECT_EQ("GPU", placer.get_device(node).type());

}
```

Where do we get the default device? Each device is [registered](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device_factory.cc#L65-L66) with a priority:

```
void DeviceFactory::Register(const string& device_type, DeviceFactory* factory,int priority)
```

The comment [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ec7929b878926c39255254e9aea992f0bc65aa68/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/device_factory.h#L56-L68) is interesting and a quick [search](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=REGISTER_LOCAL_DEVICE_FACTORY&type=) gives:

- "CPU", ThreadPoolDeviceFactory, 60
- "CPU", GPUCompatibleCPUDeviceFactory, 70
- "GPU", GPUDeviceFactory, 210

The TF-placer uses devices with higher priority if possible.
So whenever there is a GPU available **and** there is a registered kernel of the Op for the GPU **and** no manual assignment was made => it uses the GPU.

Your second question ("How to divide them") cannot be answered that easily if you care about efficiency. In most cases, there is no need to place the operation on the CPU.

As a rule of thumb: Trust the heuristics behind the scenes, if you feel no need to manually assign devices.

**edit:** As the questions was edited, here are the additional details:

The `soft_device_placement` is only [applied to nodes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/placer.cc#L322-L329), that cannot run on the intended devices. Consider training on the GPU and inference on a laptop. As each Op-Kernel is only registered to a [device type (CPU, GPU)](https://github.com/cgtuebingen/tf_custom_op/blob/master/matrix_add/kernels/matrix_add_op.cc#L81-L86) it **cannot** distribute the Op between different GPUs directly (they are the same device type).

There are mainly [two ways](https://www.tensorflow.org/performance/performance_models#variable_distribution_and_gradient_aggregation) to do distributed training. And you should care about where to place the variables. I am not sure what you are looking for. But TF allows you to [balance the placement](https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks/blob/master/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/variable_mgr.py#L34-L61) over all GPUs.

Please allow me to add one further note:
As I only use [TensorPack](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack), I know it supports distributed training in a [very easy way](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack/blob/master/tensorpack/train/multigpu.py#L117) as illustrated in the [distributed ResNet example](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack/blob/master/examples/ResNet/imagenet-resnet.py). So speaking it takes care about all this behind the scene.

Comment: nice walkthrough!

Comment: @Patwie Perfect Intro . Well I above comment says if you have two GPUs currently TF would only use one if we don't explicitly assign it to some operations . So how to work with multi GPUs ?

Comment: You need to explicitly assign a specific GPU if you want to work with multiple GPUs. There is currently no other way. Like I mentioned in the answer I suggest you looking at [TensorPack](https://github.com/ppwwyyxx/tensorpack) which is IMHO currently the best way to do distributed training even across different machines.