# Why is TensorFlow using my GPU when the device is set to the CPU

Tags: c++, tensorflow, memory-management, gpu, cpu

TensorFlow is using allocating all of my GPU memory and ignoring my commands to use the CPU, how can I fix this?

Here's the code excerpt of my `testprog`

```
Session *session;
SessionOptions opts = SessionOptions();

//force to allocate 0 memory on gpu
opts.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction(0);
opts.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_allow_growth(false);

//create session with these settings
TF_CHECK_OK(NewSession(opts, &session));
TF_CHECK_OK(session->Create(graph_def));

//set device to cpu
graph::SetDefaultDevice("/cpu:0", &graph_def);

//run arbitrary model
Status status = session->Run(classifierInput, {output_layer},{},&outputs);

TF_CHECK_OK(session->Close());
```

Calling `nvidi-smi` shows me:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.66                 Driver Version: 375.66                    |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  Quadro P4000        Off  | 0000:01:00.0     Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   50C    P0    28W /  N/A |   7756MiB /  8114MiB |     42%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1784    G   /usr/bin/X                                     139MiB |
|    0      3828    G   qtcreator                                       28MiB |
|    0      7721    C   ...testprog/build/testprog                    7585MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Why is that so?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since this question is tagged with C++. The solution is

```
tensorflow::Session *sess;
tensorflow::SessionOptions options;

tensorflow::ConfigProto* config = &options.config;
// disabled GPU entirely
(*config->mutable_device_count())["GPU"] = 0;
// place nodes somewhere
config->set_allow_soft_placement(true);
```

See the [example here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/16fabd1fc3408252d816bf53698df8f05c9ee304/tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device_test.cc#L30-L49).
And my other post, [how TensorFlow places the nodes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46243864/7443104).

**edit**: There is [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9201). You can try:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
setenv("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "", 1);
```

or

```
auto gpu_options = config->gpu_options();
gpu_options.set_visible_device_list("");
```

But this might give you `failed call to cuInit: CUDA_ERROR_NO_DEVICE`.

Comment: Now it's *only* using ~ 130 MB GPU mem

Comment: Yep, there is an open issue with Tensorflow. See my edits.

Answer (score 3):

When you set the parameters to cpu:1 it does not prevent tensorflow from initializing the GPU device.

```
session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
    device_count={'CPU' : 1, 'GPU' : 0},
    allow_soft_placement=True,
    log_device_placement=False
)
```

Also... last resort:

> `alias nogpu='export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1;'`
>
> `nogpu python disable_GPU_tensorflow.py`

or

> `setenv("CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES", "", 1);`

Comment: could you please rewrite the answer for the C++ API (see Tag)